# Facebook App Request Sent From Mobile but Not Displayed in Notification Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying  to use facebook sdk for android to send app request from my app
I am able to send the request also, however it is not showing in other user notification.

I am not able to figure out where i could be wrong, I am simply using code by facebook in developers site.

```
    public void sendApplicationRequestUsingFacebook(){
    com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(com.facebook.Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("Session Facebook", "Open");
                sendRequestDialog();
            }else{
                Log.d("Session Facebook", "Cloase");
            }

        }
    });
}


private void sendRequestDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,
                com.facebook.Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(EActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(EActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Network Error", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(EActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request sent",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(EActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }   
                }

            })
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to send app request to friends https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests